# Build an online application like facebook android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service

I am trying to build an online application for movie management. I want the application to be an online one, could any have inputs as to how to build it, as in currently i am downloading each of the dynamic content and loading the layouts which is highly inefficient. Could anyone suggest a better procedure to make an online application and guide for the same.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

That link will show you how to make a Google app engine project. The easiest way to use an online database with android. You can post, and get with very little code. What you do with the data you get back is up to you... Throw it into list views, text views, fragments, etc. But yes this is the best place to start as you need an online database or a social network would not work at all. I suggest you do the above totural and then come back with some more questions. Hope this helps!